# How can I confirm if my audio output is defective (on RPi3)?

Tags: audio, audio-playback, pulseaudio

I am wondering if maybe my audio output of my Raspberry Pi 3 is defective. I have tried to get some kind of audio output without any success so far.

I have tried any comment / tutorial on how to enable and test audio output that I could find online to get audio output - either through the headphone jack or HDMI channel, but had no luck so far.

I first installed `minibian` and tried to get audio output with `mpg321`, `aplay`, `speaker-test` and some other music players, but nothing came out.

I installed the `pulseaudio` package and changed the `raspi-config` to force `3.5mm` as well as `HDMI` audio output. I am now trying the same on `Ubuntu Mate`, but since I am getting nowhere, I wonder if anyone could tell how I could test if the audio unit works in a more or less bullet-proof way - to make sure it's not actually defective.

*Note:*

My headphones work well and the Raspberry Pi 3 just arrived, so it could very well never have worked.

Comment: Is there an HDMI device connected to a TV or monitor?

Comment: Yes, I have a monitor connected (after I started testing Ubuntu Mate). The monitor doesn't have speakers, but does have a headphone jack.

Comment: The default is to have audio output via HDMI. You can change it in /boot/config.txt.

Comment: are you referring to the HDMI ethernet channel ? I have never seen any reference to audio being output over ethernet for the RPi3. I did find some relevant settings in the boot config, but changing those from the defaults had no effect.

Comment: sorry over HDMI